# How to count the tags containing 'specific text' in xml file, irrespective of hierarchy?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have sample xml file to be parsed. How do i count the number of occurrences of a tag containing specific tags [Python] ?

```
<xml>
  <t1>fdhdhd</t1>
  <t2>fdhdhd</t2>
  <sub>
      <context>aligned</context>
  </sub>
 <context>not-aligned</context>
    <sub>
      <context>aligned</context>
  </sub>
</xml>
```

How do i count the number of occurrences of tag 'sub' containing text 'aligned' and 'not-aligned' ?

Comment: might help, https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax

Comment: you mean: `sub` containing sub-tags containing the text right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xml = '''<xml>
  <t1>fdhdhd</t1>
  <t2>fdhdhd</t2>
  <sub>
      <context>aligned</context>
  </sub>
 <context>not-aligned</context>
    <sub>
      <context>aligned</context>
  </sub>
</xml>'''

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
tree.xpath('count(//sub/context[.="aligned" or .="not-aligned"])')
```

out:

```
2.0
```

Comment: @Jackie if you have trouble on installing `lxml`, use Anaconda, it contains all the dependency you need and `lxml` is pre-installed.

Answer (score 3):

In case you'd like to do it within the standard library (i.e. without the `lxml` dependency), you can try this (assuming your xml file is `sample.xml`):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse('sample.xml')
count = 0
for e in xml.findall(".//sub[context]"):
    if e.find("context").text in ('aligned', 'not-aligned'):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

**Edit**: if I understand your comment to my answer correctly, you never want to count *both* "not-aligned" and "aligned", but always just either of the two. Also, you actually don't care which element `context` appears under. In that case

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse('sample.xml')
count = len(xml.findall(".//*[context='aligned']"))
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: Is there any way to find the count/length of tags 'context' containig text 'aligned' ? can be one-liner

Comment: Can you edit the above solution as below : from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET   tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
  root = tree.getroot() print len(root.findall('.//context')) print len(root.findall(".//*[context='aligned']")) . This looks pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: how do you handle broken xml here ? "ET.parse" will not work here ?

Comment: XML parsers are usually not designed to deal with "broken" input (as opposed to HTML parsers). You might want to try https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: ERROR : "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag:" . Do we have similar to "lxml : parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)" for "from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET" ?